# How can I use join operation in magento

Tags: magento-1

I have two tables user and address, I want to display all the contents from table user and address when id of user table matches the id of address table. I tried something like this:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
       $user_table = $this->getMainTable();
       $address_table = $this->getTable('user/address');
       $cond = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto('$user_table.user_id = $address_table.userid','');
       $where = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("user_id = ? OR ", $string).$this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("firstname = ? OR ", $string).$this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("lastname = ? OR ", $string).$this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("email = ? OR ", $string).$this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("dob = ? ", $string);
       $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from($user_table)->join(array('t2'=>$address_table), $cond)->where($where);
       $data = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchRow($select);
       return $data;
```

Someone please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of joins:

```
$table = $this->getMainTable();
    $table2 = $this->getTable('customer/entity');
    $cond = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto('t1.id = t2.customer_id','');
    $where = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto('t1.list_id = "?"',123);
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from(array('t1'=>$table))->join(array('t2'=>$table2), $cond)->where($where);
    echo $select."<br/>";
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from(array('t1'=>$table))->joinLeft(array('t2'=>$table2), $cond)->where($where);
    echo $select."<br/>";
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from(array('t1'=>$table))->joinRight(array('t2'=>$table2), $cond)->where($where);
    echo $select."<br/>";
    echo $select."<br/>";
```

[For more see here.](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/22/magento-part7-series-models-sql-operations/)